# MailKit SmtpClient Send method works for first time but no after that while using FluentScheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailkit

I created background task for my Web Application which sends a email every 15 minutes to client if there are any problems. I am using Gmail to send emails.

```
public virtual void Send(string body, string attachment)
    {
        message.From.Add(GetFromAddress());
        message.To.AddRange(GetToAddresses());
        message.Subject = "Error";
        message.Body = CreateBody(body, attachment);

        using (var SmtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!SmtpClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    ConnectToGmail(SmtpClient);
                }

                SmtpClient.Send(message);
                SmtpClient.Disconnect(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run the project then first time it gets to Send method then email is sent. But the next time it reaches Send method, then it does not send a email anymore. There is no exception thrown. Nothing in spam folder.

What could be this issue? Has anyone had anything like that?

Comment: Have you checked `Spam` folder?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing there.

Comment: I use the same SmtpClient and I don't call `Disconnect` method at all

Comment: I did not use it either. Same problem. Now added it. I thought maybe this was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I created MimeMessage once and then always added to that same message everytime. Now everytime i call send i create a new MimeMessage and now it works.

```
public virtual void Send(string body, string attachment)
    {
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(GetFromAddress());
        message.To.AddRange(GetToAddresses());
        message.Subject = "Kiosk error";
        message.Body = CreateBody(body, attachment);

        using (var SmtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!SmtpClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    ConnectToGmail(SmtpClient);
                }

                SmtpClient.Send(message);
                SmtpClient.Disconnect(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem might be that your SMTP server is not allowing you to send multiple messages with the same Message-Id, so simply changing the MessageId property each time you send might also work.